# Differentiate between faces of men and women

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, simplecv

I need to make an app that tells if the only face in a certain picture is that of a man or a woman
It would be better if it was done using python.
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: That's almost impossible because sometimes even human can't perfectly determine whether there's a man or a woman in front of him!

Comment: Have a look at Defcon 18 - Facial Recognition: Facts, Fiction, and Fsck-ups https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4CrD_zfP08 for facial detection/tracking/recognition issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem. Gender detection is what you need to do. Recently I have done gender detection using the below link and got a decent accuracy. Follow the link step by step.

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_gender_classification.html

And there is a C++ code in the above link for Face-recognizer which does this. You can get the equivalent python API's in [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/).

This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268753/face-gender-detection-library?answertab=votes#tab-top) has few more links and information.